# Getting the ID of the row c# Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, database, dbclient

Im was changing my Mysql databaseclient to the one of mysql.data.dll
from the System.data.sqlclient.

But before with sqlclient could I do this:

```
 public long insertQuery()
    {
        long lastInsertedId = 0L;
        try
        {
            lastInsertedId = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Exeption.WriteMySQLError(exception.ToString());
        }
        return lastInsertedId;
    }
dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO items (base_item, user_id) VALUES (" + BaseItem + ", " + UserId + ")");
                    Id = (uint)dbClient.insertQuery();
```

and then did i got the itemId that i just inserted 
but with the same code and with ExecuteScalar() from MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand 
Do I get a null exeption. 
so how does this work with MySqlCommand?

Command comes from this:

```
        private MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand Command;
```

Fixed it thanks to Steve heres the fixed code.

```
   public long insertQuery()
        {
            Command.CommandText += "; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
            long lastInsertedId = 0L;
            try
            {
                lastInsertedId = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nou er is een error in insertquery! :" + exception.ToString());
            }   
            return lastInsertedId;
        }
```

Comment: where comes from command??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql returns the last inserted id using the function [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html)

So your command text should be changed to something like this

```
 dbClient.setQuery(@"INSERT INTO items (base_item, user_id) VALUES (....);
                     SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
 Id = (uint)dbClient.insertQuery();
```

However your code suffers of a serious problem called SQL Injection. Passing a string formed concatenating pieces of other strings exposes your code to a security vulnerability very easy to use.

Read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and how to use a [Parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)
[SQL Injection short story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: Ow the baseitem/userid are static so its impossible to change it :p
mm and thanks gona try it :)